# Terminating SSH Session after lock

Tags: bash, ssh

I have a bash script where I SSH into my workstation. It runs a script, a few commands, and then runs a lock screen command. The problem is that the lock command renders my session useless. I am asking if there is anyway to get my session to terminate gracefully rather than ctrl+c from my remote terminal. I have something like this:

```
ssh username@$host "export DISPLAY=:0; ./my_script; ifconfig | grep 'inet '; lock& exit;"
```

Comment: Removing its handles on the terminal and exempting it from getting a HUP when the shell exits would be a place to start. `lock </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown -h` does much of the same work that `nohup` does, but without as much ugliness.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you! I implemented and it worked like a charm! +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Detach from the handles on the terminal and prevent propagation of the HUP signal, as follows:

```
lock </dev/null >/dev/null 2>&1 & disown -h
```